# select particular data from table1 which is not in table2 with where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database, fetch

I want to select data from table1 which is not in table2  but i have to select a particular data from table1

my data tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table3` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `acc_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `did` int(11) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) 



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `acc_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `table1_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `did` int(11) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) 


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `acc_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

)
```

I want to do

**select name,id from table1 where id !=(select table1_id from table2 join table3 on table2.acc_id=table3.acc_id where table2.did=4759505 and table2.acc_id=2)and table1.acc_id=2**

This above query woks fine if subquery returns 1 row but not if subquery returns multiple row

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just change the `!=` to `not in`:

```
select name, id
from table1
where id not in (select table1_id
                 from table2 join
                      table3
                      on table2.acc_id = table3.acc_id
                      where table2.did = 4759505 and table2.acc_id = 2
                ) and
      table1.acc_id = 2;
```

Note:  you should also be sure that `table1_id` in the subquery is never `NULL`.  `NOT IN` can be non-intuitive in this case.  Often, I prefer `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select name, id
from table1
where not exists (select table1_id
                  from table2 join
                       table3
                       on table2.acc_id = table3.acc_id
                       where table2.did = 4759505 and table2.acc_id = 2 and
                             table1_id = table1.id
                 ) and
      table1.acc_id = 2;
```

This handles the `NULL` value more intuitively.